# I know a word. Do you?

Tags: riddle

I know a word,

6 letters it contains,

Take away one, and 12 remains.

**What is the word?**

---

Note: I heard this riddle from a friend of mine but I knew it was online as well, since I don't want to be accused of plagiarisation, here is a possible source he may have gotten it from... http://www.doriddles.com/riddle-87

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Dozens, Take away the s and twelve remains (dozen)